# How can I open a browser window using a pushbutton in MATLAB?

Tags: user-interface, browser, matlab, button

I want to know how I can connect to an internet site when a button is pushed in a GUI. For example, if I push the button then a browser window can be popped up for "stackoverflow.com/".

Answer (score 5):

In the [callback](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uicontrol_props.html#Callback) for your [GUI push button](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uicontrol.html), you can make a call to the function [WEB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/web.html) to open a web browser to a given URL:

```
web('stackoverflow.com/');
```

For example:

```
uicontrol('Style','pushbutton',...
          'Position',[50 50 100 25],...
          'String','Go to SO!',...
          'Callback',@(hObject,eventData) web('stackoverflow.com/'));
```

Comment: That's the right way, but personally I would use the system() function or similar (http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/f0-12994.html#f0-38522) rather than web(). That lets you open the page in the user's preferred browser, not just the Matlab one.